# JavaFX Project - Some imports are not accessible

Tags: java, xml, javafx, import, project-settings

I have installed JavaFX into eclipse and created a simple project through:

```
File->New->Other-> JavaFX-> JavaFX Project
```

And my project setup is exactly like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6cZcw8_XtM

And I need to parse some XML files but when I try to import the following packages:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
```

I get the error:

```
The package javax.xml.parsers is not accesible.
The package org.w3c.dom is not accesible.
```

The thing is, these imports dont give me any error in another java project, this only happens when I create a JavaFX project.

Answer (score 1):

Ok solved my problem

Instead of creating the project like this :

```
File->New->Other-> JavaFX-> JavaFX Project
```

I simply created a standard Java project and followed the same steps.

Also, Going to `Project Properties->Java Build Path-> Libraries` for some reason my openjdk was under `Modulepath` instead of `Classpath` , so I fixed that as well.